# top 1 respected fileds in linq in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using MVC3.
i have a List of Options and List of Questions. Questions and Options are related through Question Id.

step1 : I have to take the top 1 QuestionId From Questions
step 2: I have to take the Options that are equal to top 1 QuestionId.

So I have written like this.

```
    var topqid =  (from tsk in lcquestion
                             select tsk.QuestionId).Take(1);
                int tqid = Convert.ToInt32(topqid);
                var moptions = from mop in lcoption
                               where mop.QuestionId == tqid 
                               select mop.OptionText;
```

but its giving error as unable to cast_int32........

how could i do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Which type is your tsk.QuestionId ?

Answer (score 1):

[Take](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx) will return an `IEnumberable<T>` what you need is [First](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb291976.aspx):

```
 var topqid =  (from tsk in lcquestion
                             select tsk.QuestionId).First();
```

Comment: First is what you are looking for. If there's a chance that there are no rows in lcquestion, you can also do FirstOrDefault. It will return null if there are no rows in lcquestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `Convert.ToInt32` in Linq To Sql/Entities queries.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do it without the query syntax:

```
// get the whole question object / row
var topq = lcquestion.First();

// if QuestionId is not already an int, convert
var tqid = Convert.ToInt32(topq.QuestionId);

var moptions = lcoption.Where(o => o.QuestionId == tqid).Select(o => o.OptionText);
```